# Rotate left legend chartjs

Tags: chart.js

Is their a way to rotate the legend on the left side of a bar chart vertically (in chartjs)? I can't seem to find it in the documentation.

### Current:

[image]

### Wanted:

[image]

### Code:

chartData is an array containing the char data where chartData["yas"] is equal to the "Samples" legend title

```
let myChart = new Chart(chart, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: chartData['labels'],
        datasets: [{
            label: chartData["yas"],
            data: chartData['values'],
            backgroundColor: '#6FB98F'
        }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                position: 'left'
            }
        },
        scales: {
            y: {
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true,
                    minRotation : 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with the current implementation of the legend in chart.js. You have 2 options, you can use a [html legend](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/samples/legend/html.html) and rotate that 90 degree with css. Or you can take the [legend plugin](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/src/plugins/plugin.legend.js) as a basis and write the functionality yourself to rotate it and either use it or make a pr and get it into the main lib.